Dovecot: Can I delete duplicate messages under Maildir on the server?
After a client misconfiguration, many messages have been deleted. I restored them from backups, but now there are many duplicates.
I can identify them on the server, and delete them.
But do I need to also delete the dovecot.index files and/or other dovecot* files in the affected folders, or will these be automatically updated?
